# Create Postgresql database in Heroku with Ruby (without Rails)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm currently hosting a simple Ruby script that stores URLs and Scores and saving them to YAML.  However, I'd like to save to a Postgresql database instead since the yaml file is deleted every time I restart the app.  Here's the error I'm getting in Heroku:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

Here's an example script that works locally, but throws me the above error in Heroku:

```
require 'pg'
conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'template1' )
res1 = conn.exec('SELECT * from pg_database where datname = $1', ['words'])
if res1.ntuples == 1 # db exists
  # do nothing
else
  conn.exec('CREATE DATABASE words')
  words_conn = PGconn.connect( :dbname => 'words')
  words_conn.exec("create table top (url varchar, score integer);")
  words_conn.exec("INSERT INTO top (url, score) VALUES ('http://apple.com', 1);")
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have created a Postgres database using the Heroku toolchain via `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev` (or the plan of your choice) you should have a `DATABASE_URL` environmental variable that contains your connection string. You can check that locally through `heroku pg:config`.

Using the `pg` gem (docs: http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html) - and modifying the example from there to suit -

```
require 'pg'
# source the connection string from the DATABASE_URL environmental variable
conn = PG::Connection.new(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
res = conn.exec_params('create table top (url varchar, score integer;")
```

**Update**: A slightly more complete example for the purposes of error handling:

```
conn = PG::Connection.new(ENV['TEST_DATABASE_URL'])
begin
    # Ensures the table is created if it doesn't exist
    res = conn.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS top (url varchar, score integer);")
    res.result_status
rescue PG::Error => pg_error
    puts "Table creation failed: #{pg_error.message}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! In my previous code, I was using my res1 PG::Result variable to check if the db existed (using ntuples == 1). How would one refactor that to work wit your example? THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: The database is already created for you: if you inspect the result of `heroku pg:credentials` you'll find the DB name is defined as part of the `DATABASE_URL`. Otherwise, a `try/rescue` block can catch any other more terminal errors during initialisation. See my update for a quick example.

Comment: @LeeCarl database URL contains everything necessary to start working with it: protocol name, server hostname and port, user credentials and database name. Since DBaaS generates all that for you, it makes sense for to provide all that as one large chunk of information. And so it does.

Comment: A rescue block was exactly what I needed.  Thanks guys for all the help! :3